# Hysplit not working with Mac OS update to Monterey

Tags: tcl, macos-monterey

I updated to Monterey last week and since then my Hysplit GUI is not displaying properly. it is not an issue with my laptop's display (I have changed and inverted the colours). I have attached screenshots of what it usually looks like and what it looks like now.

I think that this is an issue with Wish - which runs .tcl files. The Hysplit GUI is built on .tcl files. I have attached screenshots of what one of the examples from Wish are showing up as. I have tried to update/figure out what is wrong with Wish but I am limited in my understanding of how it works.

Thanks for the help.

---

Now:
[image: Screenshot of Hysplit GUI now]

Before:
[image: Screenshot of Hysplit GUI before]

Example Wish application:
[image: Screenshot of example Wish application]

Comment: The “Before” picture seems very similar (pixel for pixel similar!) to the Example Demo one. Did you upload the right one? (I've inlined the images for ease of reading.)

Comment: Hey! Yes I did upload the wrong images, but this has since been solved! For anyone else who has this issue I installed a different tcl interpreter via this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekCFlPu3kqI and everything is working now!

Comment: One possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391219/wish-based-tools-git-gui-gitk-showing-broken-black-ui-on-macos-monterey

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Tcl/Tk version (8.5) shipped with macOS Monterey is broken.
A possible fix:

#### use the version shipped with Homewrew

Assuming Homebrew is already setup, do:

```
$ brew upgrade
$ brew install tcl-tk
```

Then setup a link to the new version of wish:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s ../Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.12/bin/wish wish
# Eventually replace 8.6.12 with the version exposed by:
$ brew info tcl-tk
```

Restart your terminal and all wish-based utilities should work well!